# How does $|g(z)-k|<1/2|k|\Rightarrow |g(z)|>1/2|k|?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

I'm reading Ian Stewart's *Complex Analysis*, page 27, where he proves $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(1/g(z))=1/k$, and he has the following step:

> $$z\in S\;\text{and}\;0<|z-z_0|<\delta_1\;\text{implies}\;|g(z)-k|<1/2|k|$$
>
> $$\text{hence}|g(z)|>1/2|k|$$

*How is this right?*

My step would be:

> $$\text{hence}\;|g(z)|-|k| < 1/2|k|,\; |g(z)|<3/2|k|$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $|g(z)|-|k| < |g(z) - k| < |k|/2$ and $|k| - |g(z)| < |g(z) - k| < |k|/2$. Thus $|k|/2<|g(z)|<3|k|/2$.